# How to store a command and options in separate variables in bash

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-arguments, ls

I'm trying to create a bash script which asks for a directory, then asks for options (both using dialog boxes) but I can't seem to get it to work.

If the directory is `$directory` and the options are saved as `$options` I assumed the command would be:

`ls $options $directory`

But so far this hasn't worked. The command fails as it's trying to run the options as directories. Part of the problem seems to be that the input from a checklist comes back with double quotes but I'm unsure how to remove them. Also, if I run:

`ls "-A" ~`

then the command runs fine, but through the bash script (and I'v checked using the debugger) the exact same line will fail, either using variables or as a hardcoded line.

Am I missing something obvious? I can post the actual code I've used if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have to get rid of "". You can achieve it like this:

```
options3=${options3:1}
options3=${options3%?}
```

or

```
options3=`eval echo $options3`
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash

directory=$2
options=$1
options2="-l"
options3="\"-l\""

# correct
#echo "options: $options"
#ls $options $directory

#echo
#echo

# correct
#echo "options: $options2"
#ls $options2 $directory

#echo
#echo

# incorrect
# echo "options: $options3"
# ls $options3 $directory

# correct
options3=${options3:1}
options3=${options3%?}
echo "options: $options3"
ls $options3 $directory

# correct
options3=`eval echo $options3`
ls $options3 $directory
```

Comment: Will this work if the checkbox returns multiple options? I.e. if `$options="-A" "-l"` etc.

Comment: it should work, at least the last example. Why don't you try it yourself?


options="\"-l\" \"-a\"" 
echo $options3
`options3=`eval echo $options3`
echo $options3
ls $options3 $directory

Comment: I've messed something with formatting code in the previous comment. 
Just use `eval echo $options` to get rid of the double quotes, should work with multiple options

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are having problems with tilde expansion.  Use *eval* on the variable to allow the substitution.

```
#!/bin/bash
options="-A"
directory="~"
directory=`eval "echo $directory"`
ls $options $directory
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use $0 and $1 (It could also be $1 and $2, I forget)
$1 would be the first parameter. So in your case it would be the dictionary.
EX: ls car